# JQL to search all parent issues with a particular label, and include any sub-tasks of those issues

Tags: jira, jql

I want to use JQL to search all parent issues where a particular label exists, and include those issues' sub-tasks, if they exist.  I want to use this filter for a Kanban board.  I don't have the option to use plugins at this time, nor do I have access to the Rest API at this time.  Thank you in advance for your assistance!